# Conditional expectation of function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $f$ be a 1-Lipschitz function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\{X_i\}$ be an independent sequence of random variables, each with variance $\leq 1$.

Suppose we are given a function $g(x_1, \dots, x_{k}) := E\left(f\left(x_1, \dots, x_{k},X_{k+1}, \dots, X_{n}\right)\right)$ from $\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $k < n$. Finally, we define another function $v(x_1, \dots, x_{k-1}) := Var(g(x_1, \dots, x_{k-1},X_{k}))$.

I realize that this is a pretty convoluted construction, but I believe everything so far is well-defined.

Now, I have a few questions about what happens if I replace $x$s with random variables. In particular, what is $g(X_1, \dots, X_k)$? I am interpreting it as 
$$g(X_1, \dots, X_k) = E(f(X_1, \dots, X_n)|X_1, \dots, X_k),$$
is this correct?

What about $Ev(X_1, \dots, X_{k-1})$? I am interpreting this as 
$$Ev(X_1, \dots, X_{k-1}) = E\left(Var(g(X_1, \dots,X_{k})|X_1, \dots, X_{k-1})\right),$$
is this correct?

If the above interpretations are correct, how do I evaluate $E\left(Var(g(X_1, \dots,X_{k})|X_1, \dots, X_{k-1})\right)$? I would like to show that it is less than 1.

Intuitively, this should follow from the fact that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz and that $Var(X_{k}) \leq 1$.

I want to formalize the idea that $X_1, \dots, X_{k-1}$ are "fixed" (since they are being conditioned on), and that $X_{k+1}, \dots, X_n$ are also "fixed" (since they don't vary with $g$), leaving only $X_k$ to "vary", but I am having an extremely difficult pinning this down rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a well-known result about conditioning:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ take values in $(S,\mathcal{S})$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-field s.t. $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$. If $\varphi$ is a function  with $\mathsf{E}|\varphi(X,Y)|<\infty$, then
>   $$
> \mathsf{E}[\varphi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal{F}]=\psi(X)\quad\text{a.s.},
> $$ 
>   where $\psi(x):=\mathsf{E}\varphi(x,Y)$.

In your case, letting $W_k:=[X_1,\ldots, X_k]$,
$$
g(W_k)=\mathsf{E}[f(W_n)\mid W_k]
$$
and
$$
v(W_{k-1})=\mathsf{E}[(g(W_k))^2\mid W_{k-1}]-\left(\mathsf{E}[g(W_k)\mid W_{k-1}]\right)^2.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}v(W_{k-1})&=\mathsf{E}\left(\mathsf{E}[f(W_n)\mid W_k]\right)^2-\mathsf{E}\left(\mathsf{E}[f(W_n)\mid W_{k-1}]\right)^2 \\
&=\mathsf{E}[\operatorname{Var}(\mathsf{E}[f(W_n)\mid W_k]\mid W_{k-1})].
\end{align}

---

The function $g$ is $1$-Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}^k$ because
\begin{align}
|g(x)-g(y)|&\le\mathsf{E}|f(x_1,\ldots,x_k,W_{k+1},\ldots,W_n) \\
&\qquad-f(y_1,\ldots,y_k,W_{k+1},\ldots,W_n)|\le \|x-y\|.
\end{align}

Consequently,

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}v(W_{k-1})&=\mathsf{E}\operatorname{Var}\left(g(W_k)-g(\mathsf{E}[W_k\mid W_{k-1}])\mid W_{k-1}\right) \\
&\le \mathsf{E}[g(W_k)-g(\mathsf{E}[W_k\mid W_{k-1}])]^2 \\
&\le \mathsf{E}\|W_k-\mathsf{E}[W_k\mid W_{k-1}]\|^2=\operatorname{Var}(X_k).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, it was very helpful. 

I have a couple of quick questions: Should the second last line be $\mathsf{E}\left(\mathsf{E}[f(W_n)\mid W_k]^2\right)-\mathsf{E}\left(\mathsf{E}[f(W_n)\mid W_{k-1}]\right)^2$? Also, I presume the last line should have $Var(E(f(W_n)|W_k))$ instead of $Var(E(W_n|W_k))$.

How do I go about thinking about the last expression? Any ideas on how I can show that it is less than 1?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit, and for putting so much time into this. I understand if you don't want to spend more time on this, so I am accepting your answer.

But, I do believe we can improve the result, right? This allows me to bound it by $n-k$, but I think we should be able to get $Ev(W_{k-1}) \leq Var X_k$, do you agree? 

If so, any ideas on how I could approach this?

Comment: @jackson5 Updated.